# .Find not working and If statement based on results of .Find method. what expression can be passed into the .Find method?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use excel VBA to find a price in a contract saved in *.docx file. Later I assign the price into a variable and write it into the cell in a spreadsheet.

The macro works fine, at least the first half of it.

50% cases I get a clean price with no additional trash words in it and I can save it in my `price` variable, which is declared as `Long`.

The other half cases I get the price with the word I don't need.

It's always the same word "lacznej"  -  it's a Polish word, therefore I omitted some Slavic letters, but for the sake of this question it's "lacznej" and I really need to get rid of it in order to write the price into my `price` variable, which is `Long`. 
Later I write this variable value into the cell in Excel spreadsheet.

```
startPos = InStr(1, rng, textToFind6)
endPos = InStr(startPos, rng, ",00zł")        'here we get 47380, we're looking 4 ",00zł"
startPos = startPos + Len(textToFind6)        ' + 21 characters     'now start position is reassigned at 47331.
     Debug.Print Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", "")
     'up to this moment macro works fine while customers buy appartment in shares, like 1/2 or 1/3, in the next line it crashes.
          Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", "").Find   why this line crashes??
            .Text = "łącznej "       'if I find this superfluous word I want to replace it with ""
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .Forward = True
            .Execute
              If .Found = True Then
                Debug.Print Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", "")
                price = Replace(Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", ""), "łącznej ", "")
              Else
                price = Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", "")          
                price = Trim(price)
              End If
     Debug.Print price
```

This is it. 
`Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", "").Find` 
How to make this line run? I thought I'm passing string value into the .Find method. It should work with string values right??

What "invalid qualifier" means ??

The initial `Replace(Mid(rng, startPos, endPos - startPos), ".", "")` is because I have "." as a separator of millions and thousands, so the price of the house is `1.500.000` or `800.000` in word document, and I need to replace "." with "", to get a number I can read into my `price` variable.

The last lines of the macro are:

```
        Debug.Print scndRng.Address
        scndRng.Offset(0, 1) = price    'these two lines work fine.
```

Comment: It's `Range.Find`... `.Find` doesn't make sense with a `Replace` expression.

Comment: So how do I get rid of the superfluous word in the 50% of the cases, before assigning it to the Long type variable.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you should be able to just `Replace` that specific word `"lacznej"`... for example: `Dim x`, `x = "1234 lacznej"`, then `x = Replace(x, "lacznej", "")` would replace that word with a blank string.